# Read url content, unbuffered php

Tags: php, cgi, unbuffered

This function reads an url

```
 function get_url_contents($url){
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

but I want to read it unbuffered, so I can read an unbuffered cgi-script, e.g., to analyze it while it is loading?
How do I do this in php?

Comment: Good question, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do it.

Comment: Consider looking into `fopen`. You can open a connection to `$url` and `fread()` a certain amount of bytes from it in a loop, processing it as it comes through.

Comment: the problem with fopen, is that most hosts disable it from accessing urls, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fsockopen(), such as in the first example given here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php